# how-to-fix-compile-error-expected-end-sub-property-or-function

Tags: excel, vba

For my work, I'm trying to automate some analysis into a standard Excel file to do the work for me.
I thought I had assembled the right code to do so.

What I'm looking for is just a sheet where I can put the source file export from my financial programm en turn that into a more complex version with additional formulas to add some fields and the add different pivots to it.

I've have written code to basicly clean wipe the sheet where I want the sourcefile to be copied to, then I want Excel to copy all the data from the sourcefile sheet to the new sheet and then add the formulas.
I'm already getting an error on the first part.

I used the following code:

```
    enter code here
Sub TransferSourcefile()
Dim EndRow, FirstRow

    'TransferSourcefile
   Sheets("Macro sortering").Select
   Range("A4").Select
   If Sheets("Macro sortering").Range("A4").Value > 0 Then
       Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
       EndRow = Selection.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
       Sheets("Macro sortering").Range("A4:AG" & EndRow).Select
       Selection.ClearContents
   End If
   Sheets("Bronbestand").Select
    
   Sheets("Bronbestand").Select
   Range("A1").Select
   Selection.End(xlDown).Select
   EndRow = ActiveCell.Row
   Range("A1:AE" & EndRow).Select

   Selection.Copy
   Sheets("Macro sortering").Select
   Sheets("Macro sortering").Range("A4").Select
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
       :=False, Transpose:=False
   Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

```
enter code here
```

Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> when the error popup appears to copy the error text and paste it here. It will tell you what line is causing the error.

```
Sub TransferSourcefile()
      Dim EndRow, FirstRow

          'TransferSourcefile
10       On Error GoTo TransferSourcefile_Error

20       Sheets("Macro sortering").Select
30       Range("A4").Select
40       If Sheets("Macro sortering").Range("A4").Value > 0 Then
50           Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
60           EndRow = Selection.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
70           Sheets("Macro sortering").Range("A4:AG" & EndRow).Select
80           Selection.ClearContents
90       End If
100      Sheets("Bronbestand").Select
          
110      Sheets("Bronbestand").Select
120      Range("A1").Select
130      Selection.End(xlDown).Select
140      EndRow = ActiveCell.Row
150      Range("A1:AE" & EndRow).Select

160      Selection.Copy
170      Sheets("Macro sortering").Select
180      Sheets("Macro sortering").Range("A4").Select
190      Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
             :=False, Transpose:=False
200      Application.CutCopyMode = False

210      On Error GoTo 0
220      Exit Sub

TransferSourcefile_Error:

230       MsgBox "Line:" & Erl & vbCrLf & "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure TransferSourcefile"

End Sub
```

Comment: ---------------------------
Microsoft Excel
---------------------------
Line:100

Error 9 (Het subscript valt buiten het bereik) in procedure TransferSourcefile
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: Does a sheet named exactly "Bronbestand" exist?

Comment: Yes it does, I recopied your data into my vba and it works now.... maybe I had too many spaces somewhere?

Comment: Additionally: If I want to add a new row to the copied data with a formula, how do I make that row go to the exact ending of the copied data?